# "hello x" - string compare

Tags: c, string, parsing

I need to see if my `string` matches "hello X" where X is any `int`.

Basically I want to catch if its "hello 1" or "hello 100".

How best can I do it?

**Edit 0**

Thanks Andrea Bergia.

I am using your code like this:

```
int dummy;
if (sscanf(string, "hello %d", &dummy))
    /* matched */
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int dummy;
int n = sscanf(string, "hello %d", &dummy);
if (n == 1) {
    // Matched
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. Is `scanf` a costly operation if I have to do it many times? I guess, it would be batter than any string compare functions, correct?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, use a profiler and measure!

Comment: That's probably good enough.  But, believe it or not, if the matching integer is outside the range `INT_MIN`..`INT_MAX`, the code's behavior is undefined.  (In practice, I suspect that it behaves reasonably sanely in all existing implementations.)

Comment: Keith Thompson: good point raised. In my case, its enough though.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to go about it.  First thought is to use a regular expression, but that may be over kill for your requirements.

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Pattern-Matching.html